# How to supply password through command while performing SSH login?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, ssh, login

I want to perform SSH login to a machine by directly supplying password through the command line like the way we do for executing `sudo` commands as shown below:

```
echo mypass | sudo -S sh -c 'echo "blablabla" > /etc/1.txt'
```

Points to consider:

1. I don't want to use sshPass
2. I don't want to set up passwordless SSH

Comment: You may use expect for that - writing a simple script providing the password when prompted.
Basic use is fairly simple - manual will help you.
However I think it's not really the safest solution. But that's your choice, if you don't want to use ssh keys for that.

Comment: 1. Why? 2. Why?

Comment: This sound like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Storing `mypass` in a script (`echo mypass | ssh ...`) is a Well-known Really Bad Idea (Security). It makes passwords available to anyone who can read the script, or run `ps` while you're logged in to the remote system. This is a known problem, and has a well tested solution: [`ssh-copy-id`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh-copy-id.1.html). From the `man page`:

```
trusty (1) ssh-copy-id.1.gz
Provided by: openssh-client_6.6p1-2ubuntu1_i386 bug

NAME

     ssh-copy-id — use locally available keys to authorise logins on a remote
     machine

SYNOPSIS

     ssh-copy-id [-n] [-i [identity_file]] [-p port] [-o ssh_option]
                 [user@]hostname
     ssh-copy-id -h | -?

DESCRIPTION

     ssh-copy-id is a script that uses ssh(1) to log into a remote machine
     (presumably using a login password, so password authentication should be
     enabled, unless you've done some clever use of multiple identities).  It
     assembles a list of one or more fingerprints (as described below) and
     tries to log in with each key, to see if any of them are already
     installed (of course, if you are not using ssh-agent(1) this may result
     in you being repeatedly prompted for pass-phrases).  It then assembles a
     list of those that failed to log in, and using ssh, enables logins with
     those keys on the remote server.  By default it adds the keys by
     appending them to the remote user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (creating the
     file, and directory, if necessary).
```

Your unwillingness to set up passwordless SSH logins could be addressed by using an alternate SSH key (on the originating system) and only `ssh-add`ing that key when  you want to login to the remote system.