# Shell script ssh to login multiple servers with password passing from a file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Shell script ssh to login multiple servers with passing password from a file

for example:
Password file name : `password.txt` and the password is "test123".

`ssh_script`:

```
  ssh testuser@testserver
  <<< Here I need to get the password from a file >>>
```

It should read a password from a file and entered into server.

Comment: Your script lacks a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: I dont want to use other command. using ssh command need to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to supply password through command while performing SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720979/how-to-supply-password-through-command-while-performing-ssh-login) and [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login). @j-money If it has been answered already, please flag the question as duplicate next time.

Answer (score 0):

Just like me and others say, this is a bad idea.

```
$ SSH_ASKPASS="/opt/bin/password.sh" sh -c 'setsid ssh user@localhost'
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH_ASKPASS="/opt/bin/password.sh" setsid ssh user@localhost
```

/opt/bin/password.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo test1234
```

The idea is to set up ssh in a new session with `setsid` and use a ssh_pass agent to supply the password.

Comment: Hi, @bac0n, it is also possible to use `sshpass -f "/path/to/passwordfile" ssh ...`.

Comment: Obviously I missed it :)